# Use Lens as `map`

Tags: haskell, lenses

I want to convert this line of code `map (^?! ix 0) [[0, 1], [4, 5], [9, 1]]` to entirely use lenses, so something like `[[0, 1], [4, 5], [9, 1]] & each . ix 0`. However, the types don't match up. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `folded`:

```
Prelude Control.Lens> [[0, 1], [4, 5], [9, 1]] ^.. folded . ix 0
[0,4,9]
```

Works on any `Foldable`.

Also, if you plan to always extract the first element, perhaps it would be clearer to use the `_head` traversal from `Control.Lens.Cons` instead of `ix`.

```
[[0, 1], [4, 5], [9, 1]] ^.. folded . _head
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use either of

```
Prelude Control.Lens> [[0, 1], [4, 5], [9, 1]] & each %~ (^?! ix 0)
[0,4,9]
Prelude Control.Lens> [[0, 1], [4, 5], [9, 1]] ^.. each . ix 0
[0,4,9]
```

The first corresponds to precisely what you wrote, using the unsafe `(^?!)` operator, which means that it can give an error. The second is safer by leaving out empty lists.

They work in somewhat different ways: The first creates a modified version of your original structure, which corresponds more to what `map` does, and it can be used on structures that aren't lists.

The second creates a list summary of your structure using the lens fold provided; although it can be used with many kinds of structures, the *result* is always a list.

You can also replace `each` by `traverse` (or, as @danidiaz points out, the slightly more general `traversed`) in this. The former works for many special things like tuples, while the latter works for any `Traversable`.

Comment: Perhaps you mean `traversed` from `Control.Lens.Traversal`, instead of `traverse`?

Comment: @danidiaz Nope, I mean `traverse`. Although it isn't *from* lens, it's considered an essential part of it.

Comment: @danidiaz Oh I see, *both* work here. It seems `traversed` is more general, allowing indices.

Comment: I wasn't aware that one could use `traverse` directly. But looking at the type, I should have been.